# how to make winxp ms-dos virtual machine work like win98 ms-dos especially graphics

Tags: c, graphics, virtual-machine, dos

Initially...

I started programming in C. that was was 10 years back(college). The IDE i used was Turbo C++ IDE.

4. All my c programs were 16bit.
5. Memory Model : Huge.
6. Graphics : 4bit (16 colors).
7. Graphics Driver: EGAVGA.BGI
8. Resolution: 640x480.
9. OS: MS-DOS 6.0 (under windows98 it is 7.0 - which always gave an accelerated execution of code)
10. Sample programs were [my computer like win3.1 still have some pending work], [paint brush - 16 colors], [graphics mouse pointer generator], 16 bit font generator... and so on..
    (these i have not yet published anywhere).

It is huge(memory model) because i extensively used C Graphics Library of Borland Turbo C.

Here is my request...

I wanted to document my work. Just in leisure time. and to just rewind the old concepts
and to implement the same in win32 api.
*I like the way i wrote the codes and i really enjoyed seeing the outout as expected but still wanting more for which i never gave up but it got outdated and i am with win32api.*

The emulation of win98 16bit graphics was perfect. **BUT** in windows xp the virtual machine output was totally different and the graphics was shabby when i run my graphics programs(GUI).

Because of this i could not take a print screen of a module.
One alternative i have is to use a win98 machine... run my programs and then can do the print screen.

What i thought was there should be an option to emulate the real 16 bit environment in windows xp  like in windows98. So i am here to get some suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Not really programming related, so voting to migrate to superuser.

Comment: Since my question is related to machine code execution environment you have voted to migrate this to superuser... is it so? hope everything else will retain except this question in superuser.

Comment: nope, I voted to migrate to superuser because this is not about programming - it is about how to run software using another piece of software. However, I'm the only voter (5 are needed) so there is little danger of this question getting actually migrated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [DOSBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSBox)? It's something people use to emulate an old DOS environment for games. Try it out.

DOSBox comes with the emulated hardware most games and graphical applications from that era need (VESA VGA modes, Soundblaster/Adlib sound...)

Also, see the [comparison of platform virtual machines on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtual_machines)

Comment: I second DOSBox. I'd say it's a better choice than most other VM platforms, because it emulates a legacy machine from the DOS days rather than a current model.

Comment: @tdammers yup, none of the big virtualizers seems to do the job right!

Comment: Awww man, now I'm left with an itching desire to play Commander Keen V and that one Apogee game with the kid with that triple slingshot.....

Comment: I will check that and will add my comments. Just give me some time.

Comment: DOSbox is really working well. It is very simple to use. and... i have a lot of work ahead with dosbox. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For running MS-DOS applications you may use [DOS-Box](http://www.dosbox.com/). It runs even on Windows Vista and 7.

Comment: I will check that and will add my comments. Just give me some time.